# php array_unique not working as expected

Tags: php, array-unique

I am trying to learn how to use array_unique, so I made some sample code and I didn't get what I expected.

```
$array[0] = 1;
$array[1] = 5;
$array[2] = 2;
$array[3] = 6;
$array[4] = 3;
$array[5] = 3;
$array[6] = 7;
$uniques = array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);
for($i = 0; $i < count($uniques); $i++)
    echo $uniques[$i];
```

For example this gives me the output of '15263' but not 7. After a few test I think that it stops looking after it finds the first duplicate. Is that what is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reason for `$uniques` output is

```
 Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 3
    [6] => 7
)
```

Your array doesn't contain key `5`, but in your `for` loop `echo $uniques[$i];` not hold the value of `echo $uniques[5];`. that is the reason value `7` is missing.

Try this,

```
foreach($uniques as $unique){
   echo $unique;
}
```

instead of

```
 for($i = 0; $i < count($uniques); $i++)
```

OR, you can re-index the array using `array_values($uniques)` and use,

```
  $uniques = array_values($uniques);
  for($i = 0; $i < count($uniques); $i++)
   echo $uniques[$i];
```

Comment: Your array value doesn't contain key `5`, thats why

Comment: Why doesn't it contain `5`? That's the question that needs to be addressed. Here's the answer: It is because `array_unique()` preserves keys. [The documentation](http://php.net/array_unique) states: `Note that keys are preserved`. Since you're using a `for` loop which operates on the array on the basis of numeric indexes, a missing position in the array will mean that it will not get echoed. Had you [enabled error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1438393), you'd have seen an error message saying `Undefined offset`.

Answer (score 9):

Since `array_unique` preserves the keys, you can’t access the array `$uniques` properly with a `for` loop. Either use a `foreach` loop or change the seventh line of your code to:

```
$uniques = array_values(array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR));
```

Comment: @mucle6: It is because the `$uniques` array keys are **not continuous**. You need to re-index it for the `for` loop to work: https://eval.in/101407

Comment: @AmalMurali Sorry, I had to write this answer in a hurry and leave StackOverflow immediately afterwards, so there was no scope to update my answer and make it more lucid/elaborate. Now I’m glad to see that the accepted answer and your comments have said all I had to say (and more than that, indeed). Thank you especially for the precious demo.